# Build Failed: Program Type Already Present

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I have searched online about this error and the issue always seems to end up being some sort of dependency conflict. I think I am supposed to add `exclude` after certain dependencies, but I am unsure which one(s). It's also unclear based on the error which dependency I should actually exclude; all I know is that the `group` is probably `com.android.support`...

Here's what I've tried:

1. Adding `multiDexEnabled true` to my `defaultConfig` block in `build.gradle`.
2. Cleaning the project in Android Studio.
3. Manually deleting (from the file system) the entire `.gradle` directory.
4. I've made sure `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are the same.
5. I've made sure all my Android dependencies use the same version (namely `26.1.0`).

Despite all this, I still get this error when I build:

```
Program type already present: android.support.compat.R$bool
```

and from the Java compiler:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
F:\ExampleProject\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\115, 
F:\ExampleProject\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0
```

Here is my module's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.exampleproject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.0'
}
```

and lastly, my project's `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help in rectifying this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error. :(

Comment: I am able to build it successfully, which android studio version are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with Glide 4.1.0. Use the version 4.1.1 instead which fix the bug by remove the R*.class file from their dependencies. ([source](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/commit/1325d87d37693214c0cde86f5de0380c396772b0))

Comment: Thanks for the info + source. I regret to report that the error is still appearing after removing that line (in addition to adding the Glide excludes that were suggested in the other answer).

Comment: @user9712684 I found the problem inside glide.

Comment: Wow, that is a really sneaky bug! Thank you so much, that has fixed the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of Glide library. Try to exclude the support library from it with:

```
// add support-fragment removed from Glide.
implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0"

implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.0') {
   exclude group: 'com.android.support'
   exclude module: 'support-fragment'
   exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

You can see the support library inside Glide at [Glide build.gradle](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/build.gradle)

Comment: The error remains the same. Is there something more I should be doing besides cleaning & deleting the .gradle directory before I try to rebuild? I'm paranoid that it's still producing the error because of build files hanging around somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'support-fragment'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
```